# Why can't I use Related Model created with same request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have one table in which I store password reset tokens. There are 4 fields in that table. They are `user_id` , `token` , `created_at` and `updated_at`.

What I want to do is, Check if user already has password reset token or not. If a user already has password reset token, I want to send an email with the same token. If a user does not have a token, I want to create token and then send the email.

Problem is, I can send the email if token is already created. But, I am getting the error `Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/project_name/resources/views/emails/passwordResetLink.blade.php)`.

Why can't I access the password reset token with `$user->passwordResetLink->token` directly after creating the record in the database? Here is my code.

```
$user = User::findByUsername(request('username'));
if($user)
{
    if(count($user->passwordResetLink))
    {
        $user->passwordResetLink->save();
    }
    else
    {
        $token = md5(str_random(16));

        $record = new PasswordReset;
        $record->user_id = $user->id;
        $record->token = $token;
        $record->save();
    }

    Mail::to($user)->send(New \App\Mail\PasswordResetLink($user));
    return 1;
}
```

I am trying to access user's password reset token using `$user->passwordResetLink->token`. It's working fine if the record is already created but not working if the record does not exist.

**PS:** I am using `save()` because `touch()` isn't working because I don't have `id` field in my `password_resets` table in the database. let me know what's wrong with the code. I know `save()` won't work as I am not updating anything!

**UPDATE:** I solved my error by replacing the Mail line to `Mail::to($user)->send(New \App\Mail\PasswordResetLink(User::find($user->id)));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change a related model after loading the primary model, this will cause the relation of the primary model to be outdated, one could solve this by reloading the relationship.

In your case you could use:

```
$user->load('passwordResetLink');
```

before

```
Mail::to($user)->send(New \App\Mail\PasswordResetLink($user));
```

This will reload only the `PasswordResetLink` and prevent having to reload the whole object.

Comment: Yeah! I also deleted my comments!